# cloning the Linux hard drive to an exteranl USB Drive?

Tags: backup

Ok, so I do not want to have the drive bootable, I do not want any existing data destroyed on the target device, all I want to do is clone the hard drive to an external source, much like I could do with Acronis on the PC. Preferably with a GUI. Although command line is okay with clear instructions.

That way if anything really bad happens, instead of going through the entire process of re-installing OS, updates, installing programs etc etc, it's all there in one image!

I have searched google and although I have found many apps that propose they can do this, they actually cannot without meeting all the criteria above!

Does anyone here have any suggestions?

Comment: 5 seconds spent in Google: https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/2-methods-to-clone-your-linux-hard-drive/

Comment: As I wrote, I have looked at several "tools" those ones included, and they CANNOT do as I want in the OP - what you think I didn't already Google? Read the full OP!!

Comment: This is rude man. Just because the tools mentioned in this link are able to do exactly what you need. I use clonezilla to backup and restore the system in case if it will crash. You can also use rsync but this is a software which runs in terminal like dd. Just learn how to use for example clonezilla and stop complaining, please.

Comment: no not rude at all imo - and it is not complaining either. I asked a specific question and advised I had already searched (and tried a few) for a tool that did what I needed but couldn't find one. So after doing all of that I posted here. Your comment indicating I had not done any research before posting the question, was, imo, the rude part! You are obviously a Linux expert and look at these things from an experts p.o.v. and perhaps forget that you started somewhere as well and that you probably asked many noob questions too.

Comment: Unfortunately I was not asking never anyone in the Internet. All I did was to look for the solution on my own. I wrote that using clonezilla you can make an image of the source disk and save it as an image file on a target drive. All you need is space on a target drive. I have no idea what you do not understand. Please read the manual from clonezilla and check how this program works, because it exactly do what you need. I am just curious how many times should it be repeated. There is no possibility to destroy anything if you know what exactly you are doing.

Comment: yep, and that's the salient point ;) if you know EXACTLY what you are doing!! On a windows system I could do this in my sleep! I did try clonezilla, but it destroys data on the target drive, as I wrote in the OP, I did not want this to happen as the target drive happens to have a lot of other data on it!

Comment: Clonezilla does not destroy the data when you clone the source disk to image not from disk to disk. If you want to use any software first you need to read the documentation. You just made one wrong step in clonezilla and that is why you wrote that it destroys the data on target drive.

Comment: ok, I'll go and have another go at clonezilla then...and can this be done from the eOS boot USB using the "Try" option?

Comment: Guide: https://clonezilla.org/show-live-doc-content.php?topic=clonezilla-live/doc/01_Save_disk_image

Comment: Thanks - fwiw, I DID read the guides I could find, but did find it rather confusing...anyhoo I'll check out the link you provided. Thanks for your patience and help :)                                                                                                                                          EDIT: that was the guide I tried and knowing a misstep could wipe the system drive, and being unfamiliar with Linux terminology and syntax, I found the whole thing confusing.

Comment: sda is first disk, sdb is second, sdc third etc. sda1 is first partition of the first drive sdb1 is first partition of the second drive etc. So by analogy. Guide describes step by step what should be done. sda by default is source drive, sdb is usually a bootable usb stick with clonezilla, sdc is a target drive where you copy the whole sda as image. The guide describes the situation when you do not have the sdc drive as target but sdb (bootable usb drive with clonezilla) isna target drive. Yes, it is not intuitive.

Comment: I would recommend to first install system in Virtual Box and practice cloniing on additionall virtual disks in Virtual Box. Linux is for experts IMHO.